# Laravel's foreach exception

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-livewire

I have registered all faculties of each school, schools can have the same faculties but different prices also each school has several faculties, in my table **School_faculty** there are therefore schools that are repeated (two, three see four times). I want to display the list of all schools in one view but I don't want the schools to repeat in the view. I used Laravel Livewire for instant search.

My Livewire Compoment

```php
class SchoolList extends Component
{
    public $query;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.school-list', [
            'faculty' => School_faculty::where('filiere', 'like', '%'. $this->query . '%')->get(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

My view blade

```html
@foreach($faculty as $School_faculty)
    <option>{{ $School_faculty->nom }}</option>
@endforeach
```

My schema School_faculty

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('school_faculties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('filiere');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I have tried several solutions but nothing works. Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: `dd` your models result and see if you actually get results. Probably from your query you are getting an empty collection back?

Comment: I do not understand your DB Schema, can you show us how it is ? Is `School_faculty` a `pivot` table ? Also, try adding `->distinct()` after your `where` and before your `get`.

Comment: I added the `School_faculty` table to the question. By the way I have two tables which register the faculties. a table which records all the details of each faculty and another which allows to associate a faculty with a school and this table is `School_faculty`. In this table there are schools which repeat themselves since a school has several faculties. Now I want to display the list of all the schools present in the `School_faculty` table but I don't want a repetition of schools in my list. How can i do this ?